# How to position a div below a fixed position div?

Tags: html, fixed

I have a navigation bar that has a fixed position.
Now the rest of my content gets put below this navigation bar since the position of that bar is fixed.
How can I position the rest of my content below my fixed navigation bar?

https://gyazo.com/dad3fc7fc35e65a4ad73fd0da2c6ffa7
*As you can see a part of my content disappears below my fixed navigation bar.*

```
<div class="header" id="header">

    <div class="menu1" id="menu1">

        <div class="name">Jan de Sterke</div>

        <div class="menu_item_holder">
            <div class="menu_item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
            <div class="menu_item"><a href="sco.php">SCO</a></div>
            <div class="menu_item"><a href="uex.php">UEX</a></div>
            <div class="menu_item"><a href="dev.php">DEV</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1C2023;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 2.5% 0 2.5% 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

De div below my navigation bar is a colored line.

CSS for this line:

```
    .headerpic {
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background: #fc4a1a;
    }
```

I have tried to use the following JavaScript code to fix the problem, but it is not working.

```
    let heightvalue = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
    let content = document.getElementById('headerpic');
    content.style.marginTop = heightvalue + "px";
```

---

My JavaScript code is actually working.

```
let heightvalue = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
let content = document.getElementById('headerpic');
content.style.marginTop = heightvalue + "px";
```

I don't know why it wasn't working before. Next problem is that this margin-top value needs to be re-calculated everytime the window gets resized. Currently it calculates a value and sets it as a margin-top at the beginning of the loading. When I resize the window this same value stays there, which causes blank spaces to appear.

EDIT: This problem can be solved by rerunning the code on the window resize event. (JavaScript window resize event) The code for my page is:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    let heightvalue = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
    let content = document.getElementById('headerpic');
    content.style.marginTop = heightvalue + "px";
};
```

Comment: Hello - I'm afraid a screen recording isn't all that useful. People really need to see your code to help you. Please edit your question and add the relevant code sections.

Comment: Add what you did !

Comment: Try to put the Navbar div outside the content div

Comment: Added code to give a better view on the situation. The bar is not inside the content div. The 'bottom: 0;' in the header style is not doing much, it was part of things I tried to fix it. The background properties are removed as well, as the background is set to a color and no longer an image.

Comment: @JandeSterke - I have edited my answer, so see if it suits you better.

Comment: @JandeSterke - hopefully my last edit will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS flexbox might help avoid having to use JavaScript, although it's difficult to model without the actual content you are using.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  color: #fff;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1C2023;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fc4a1a;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  HEADER
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id commodo neque, ac suscipit lorem. Pellentesque quis elit eget ipsum mollis finibus in eget enim. Maecenas dictum ipsum metus, quis consequat erat dictum vitae. Nam commodo mi a tempus
    vehicula. Praesent sit amet dignissim tellus. In ornare mi quis neque luctus tempor. Sed eleifend massa magna, semper pharetra odio tempor nec. Nam cursus pharetra condimentum. Etiam gravida tortor sit amet risus commodo ultrices. Integer accumsan
    velit et velit tempor tempus. Nam ornare consequat lorem, vel vulputate massa lobortis rhoncus. Vivamus placerat augue sed egestas porttitor.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt cursus est, at ultricies enim. Ut tempor eleifend sapien, in bibendum nisl rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin feugiat magna justo, at euismod turpis porta et. Curabitur lobortis efficitur
    erat eu consectetur. Sed faucibus tincidunt malesuada. Integer ut lectus odio. Etiam venenatis purus eget mauris laoreet maximus. Integer volutpat, felis sit amet iaculis vestibulum, tellus enim scelerisque odio, sed dapibus diam ante ut justo. Donec
    ac scelerisque purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras consequat porta pretium. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>

  <p>Fusce facilisis nisl condimentum, gravida odio blandit, rhoncus quam. Etiam eu est tincidunt, volutpat neque quis, consequat mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam varius leo non felis sollicitudin, ac aliquam tellus euismod. Donec mollis luctus ante ut tincidunt.
    Cras purus enim, vehicula eget placerat feugiat, tempus non lorem. Sed vestibulum purus eget leo dictum lobortis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id commodo neque, ac suscipit lorem. Pellentesque quis elit eget ipsum mollis finibus in eget enim. Maecenas dictum ipsum metus, quis consequat erat dictum vitae. Nam commodo mi a tempus
    vehicula. Praesent sit amet dignissim tellus. In ornare mi quis neque luctus tempor. Sed eleifend massa magna, semper pharetra odio tempor nec. Nam cursus pharetra condimentum. Etiam gravida tortor sit amet risus commodo ultrices. Integer accumsan
    velit et velit tempor tempus. Nam ornare consequat lorem, vel vulputate massa lobortis rhoncus. Vivamus placerat augue sed egestas porttitor.</p>

  <p>Integer tincidunt cursus est, at ultricies enim. Ut tempor eleifend sapien, in bibendum nisl rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin feugiat magna justo, at euismod turpis porta et. Curabitur lobortis efficitur
    erat eu consectetur. Sed faucibus tincidunt malesuada. Integer ut lectus odio. Etiam venenatis purus eget mauris laoreet maximus. Integer volutpat, felis sit amet iaculis vestibulum, tellus enim scelerisque odio, sed dapibus diam ante ut justo. Donec
    ac scelerisque purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras consequat porta pretium. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>

  <p>Fusce facilisis nisl condimentum, gravida odio blandit, rhoncus quam. Etiam eu est tincidunt, volutpat neque quis, consequat mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam varius leo non felis sollicitudin, ac aliquam tellus euismod. Donec mollis luctus ante ut tincidunt.
    Cras purus enim, vehicula eget placerat feugiat, tempus non lorem. Sed vestibulum purus eget leo dictum lobortis.</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: Removed additional div and styled body to use flexbox layout. Adjusted to make header div fixed.

Comment: Hmm, I understand your fix, but I personally dislike creating a div that contains youre entire page. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: @JandeSterke - sure, although that's just an illustration. You could style the `body` and not have an extra div.

Comment: How does this work with a fixed positioned div? (the header)

Comment: @JandeSterke - you were right, it didn't! It does now =)

Answer (score 0):

An element that has `position: fixed` is removed from the flow of the document like absolutely positioned elements. In fact they behave almost the same, only fixed positioned elements are always relative to the document, not any particular parent, and are unaffected by scrolling.

My recommendation is to set a `margin-top` to the content so that the top menu won't overlay it. 
You can do that with CSS like below:

```
#navBar {
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:0
}
#content{
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Updated Solution for variable navbar height with a little Javascript:**

**CSS**

```
#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var contentPlacement = $('#navBar').position().top + $('#navBar').height();
    $('#content').css('margin-top',contentPlacement);
});
```

Comment: I know, forgot to mention that the navigation bar doesn't have a set height.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, take a look at my post again. I have put in a JavaScript code I tried to use and that I think should work, but isnt.

Comment: My code works just fine for me, you can accept it as an answer if it helped you and is similar with what you did in the end.